# limit of $P(X = 1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm having problems solving this exercise:

Let $X_k$, for  $k=1,2,...,n$ be i.i.d random variables over {$\frac{1}{n},...,1$}. Define $X = \mathrm{max}[X_1, X_2,...,X_n]$ and compute the limit of $P(X = 1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

The biggest problem for me is that I don't really understand what they mean and what they are asking for and therefore I have no clue how to start solving this. For example, if $n=3$, does that mean $X_n$ is distributed over $[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}]$ or $[\frac{1}{3}, 1]$?

I noticed I can't simply use the probability function or density function. I tried both and none gave me the right answer, also don't know if this is continuous or discrete, but I would think the {$\frac{1}{n},..., 1$} suggests it is a discrete case.

I wish I could ask a more specific question, but I don't understand the question enough to even do that, and I would very much like a kick in the right direction here...

Comment: To prevent a possible confusion it would help having the limit index ($n$ in your case) in the expression of which you are taking the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution.

$X_i: \Omega \rightarrow \{\dfrac{1}{n},...,1\}, i = 1,2,...,n$.
Define $Y_n = max\{X_1, X_2,...,X_n \}$.

$P(Y_n = 1) = P(\cup_{i = 1}^{n} (\omega: X_i(\omega) = 1))$

$= P(\cap_{i = 1}^{n} (\omega: X_i(\omega) = 1)^{c})$

$ = \Pi_{i = 1}^n P( (\omega: X_i(\omega) = 1)^{c})$

$ = \Pi_{i = 1}^n (1 - P(\omega:X_i(\omega) = 1)) $

$ = \Pi_{i = 1}^{n} (1 - \dfrac{1}{n}) $

$ = (1 - \dfrac{1}{n})^{n}$

Hence, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(Y_n = 1) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 - \dfrac{1}{n})^{n} = \dfrac{1}{e}  $